# Ormlite Issue in year /date comparison android

Tags: android, date

Compare date with following query :

```
arrListMonitoringForms = monitoringFormsDao.queryBuilder().where().lt("CreatedDate", date ).query();
```

I want to get form which created date is less than given date.This code working fine with same year.

Example : *created date =1/25/2018* and *date =12/25/2017*. it gives forms of this *date :1/25/2018*, which is wrong.

Comment: i don't understand your problem. You mean you get the result but with wrong date or you mean the end query statement is wrong and return wrong data?

Comment: My issue is my ormlite does not work on year with MM/dd/yyyy is format .